# How can I get the version number of git running on server?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm a git newbie.

I'm working on a project on GitHub, and I have some problems (I'll detail them in a later posts if further checks don't succeed) pushing my commits to remote repository.

I'd like to check which version of git is running on GitHub servers. Is there any git command to perform such task? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do know that the GitHub website currently does have a problem right?
It should be ok by now. See [its twitter](http://twitter.com/github).

Regarding your question, I am not sure there is a way, except by asking them on their support.

Edit: [which I did](http://support.github.com/discussions/repos/2156-what-version-of-git-is-running-on-github-server).
The current version (December 16th) of Git running on GitHub is the **1.6.4.3**

Edit2: [From last April](http://twitter.com/chacon/status/12849938615) to today (July 17th, 2010), they are on 1.7+: 1.7.0.2 right now (look at the [comment of that SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224059/do-you-know-of-a-good-pro-con-paper-on-version-control-system-git-mercurial-svn/3224114#3224114)).
There is still (to my knowledge) no easy way to get that information directly from the GitHub page though.

Answer (score 0):

git is not bzr.  I don't ever recall them changing their repo formats, so pretty much any two versions can push and pull between each other and they don't arbitrarily kill off the access to your repositories for no apparent reason.

The closest I've come to an exception there was using a 1.4 or earlier back in the day (before they formalized remotes) and not being able to make sense of remote vs. local branches.  Even then, it *worked* just fine.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/gittip/building.gittip.com/pull/41

Not sure if it's a git bug, or pushes from shallow clones have changed.