# Git version is different between remote and local copy

Tags: git, version, local

Do you think I will have any kind of problem by using different git software versions between the remote and local copy? In my case the remote is 1.6.5.7 and the local is 1.6.5.1 (few bug fixes)

Thx ;)

Comment: I have a git repo setup using 1.6.5.? and have pushed/pulled from a machine with 1.4.?(not under my control) with no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.5.x do not introduced any repository format incompatibility.
One good example of that, is the difference between local Git and GitHub Git versions:
[GitHub runs with with 1.6.4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913677/how-can-i-get-the-version-number-of-git-running-on-server) and supports any 1.5.x clients.

Even the upcomming Git 1.7 will not introduce any major issues, only [policy changes](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=126042911404762&w=2).

Answer (score 3):

You will have no problems. Git is generally compatible between even major version changes; minor version differences should never introduce any incompatibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Minor revs are generally completely compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Obvious, more general answer: try it and see!

Comment: +1! When did “I’ll try myself first before I pester other people” die?

Comment: LOL! Well, now my answer will be indexed by search engine and no one wll bother you again :P